# Git: fatal: repository '' does not exist

Tags: git

Проблема: не могу скопировать репу, в папку выдает ошибку fatal: repository '' does not exist . При копировании на диск, все проходит нормально, в чем дело?

```
$ git clone  ssh://git@gitlab.....
fatal: repository '' does not exist
```

Comment: Эм.. Тупой совет, но попробуй лишний пробел убрать?

Comment: так и было, очевидно, при копировании зацепил пробел, будьте внимательны! :)

Comment: Убрал дополнительные метки. Проблема не специфична ни для Windows, ни для Gitlab. Запросто воспроизвелась бы с Linux & GitHub.

Comment: @Qwertiy если бы только пробел, проблемы бы не было. Там невидимые символы, которые git считает первым аргументом `clone`.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, я читал ответ. Впрочем, мой вариант оказался довольно близким и мог бы помочь)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В выполняемой команде есть четыре «невидимых» символа [U+0096](https://unicode-table.com/en/0096/). Git воспринимает их как первый аргумент команды `clone` — а первым идёт URL репозитория. Конечно, такой репозиторий не существует.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]